# How to see tweets from specific people I follow

Tags: twitter

I follow 300+ individuals in my Twitter account and feeds are falling in place but I miss tweets from 10+ important person I follow. Is there a way I can customize my timeline to get to see tweets from 10+ accounts on the top?

Comment: Have you considered creating [a list](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460) for those accounts you want to make sure you see?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [list](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460) and add all 10+ people into that list. Later you can visit anytime that list and you'll see a timeline of tweets from the accounts included in that list.

You can make this list private or public.

Or if you can turn on mobile notification for those accounts and everytime they will tweet, you will get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Twitter]

On the important page, click the gear (Settings) and click 'Turn on mobile notifications'